# Are keys removed when memcache data expires?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm currently working on adding memcache to an app running on GAE/J.  I have a question about how production memcache behaves when values expire, if they're keys are also removed.

The closest I could find to answering this question is here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html#How_Cached_Data_Expires

I know I can't rely on values staying in memcache; and I don't, but what I am wondering, is if  the keys which map to those values are also removed.

In other words, if I do

`mycache.contains("key")`

**Will this still be true after a value is pushed out of the cache?**

Side note:  Don't think it makes a difference; but just in case, I'm using the async memcache from the memcache service and get a hold of it like this:

`MemcacheServiceFactory.getAsyncMemcacheService();`

I'm asking this because I'm not doing the typical

`if(cache.get("key") == null)`

I store null values when they come back from the datastore so I don't constantly lookup the null value.  And I do take care to make sure to remove the key when it can possibly change.  So just because the memcache lookup returns null, I work on the assumption that the query is in fact null; but I do ensure that when other queries which could change that happen that the null lookup gets removed.  That is why I'm using `cache.contains("key")` as opposed to `cache.get("key") == null`

Comment: Keys and values are not separable; it wouldn't make any sense if they were.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, `mycache.contains("key")` will return false if the value had been evicted from the memcache service. This behavior is documented in the Javadoc of the [low-level Memcache API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).